# How to execute shell command for snpsift from python in a script

Tags: python

How can i execute the following command with input (`All_20180418.vcf.gz`, `A_annot.vcf`) and output (`A_annotated_2.vcf`) arguments from a python script ?

```
java -Xmx12G -jar SnpSift.jar annotate -id All_20180418.vcf.gz  A_annot.vcf > A_annotated_2.vcf
```

should i use import os and import subprocess ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but if you want to know how to run that command from within a python script, then yes- subprocess is a good option. If I understand you correctly, you could do something like the following:

```
import subprocess
process_list = ["java", "-Xmx12G", "-jar", "SnpSift.jar", "annotate", "-id", "All_20180418.vcf.gz",  "A_annot.vcf", ">", "A_annotated_2.vcf"]
result = subprocess.run(process_list)
print(result.stdout)
```

where result.stdout is the stdout from the command run

Comment: Ok this is more or less what i want. and if i want to pass the input output as arguments ?